# Increasing text size in MuPAD?

Tags: matlab, font-size, symbolic-math

MuPAD's text output is ridiculously small for me to read, and although every time I adjust the size, it does not seem to save my preferences. Is there any way to set MuPAD's text size so that it stays as I would like it to? Thanks! btw I am on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the font size in the preferences menu:

matlab→Preferences→Notebook→Default Formats...

You can also change the text size as shown [here](https://img.skitch.com/20120407-3wh4dw9g66u42pdbf9t4jcqcx.jpg) and switch the pagination as shown [here](https://img.skitch.com/20120407-cex5cws1855ysxtapqpkfqm2e9.jpg)